# DataGridView.Click vs RowHeaderMouseClick

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Just out of curiosity, how do you stop the `DataGridView.Click` event from stealing the "thunder" from the `RowHeaderMouseClick` event?

When I click the ROW HEADER, the `DataGridView.Click` event is fired.
When I DISABLE the `DataGridView.Click` event, the `RowHeaderMouseClick` event is fired, as desired.

Apparently, the ROW HEADER is part of the DataGridView--therefore, I guess, technically, it is performing as it should.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something... however... I am not following what you are trying to do. Obviously if you click a row header, then the “GRIDS” `MouseClick` event will indeed fire, however, the grids `RowHeaderMouseClick` event will also fire after this. If you do NOT click on a row header, then the `MouseClick` event obviously will fire but the `RowHeaderMouseClick` event will NOT fire… so I am not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: In a nutshell:  Click ROW HEADER--Sort column; Click ROW--Fire DataGridView.Click event.

Comment: @user1845588 _"Click ROW HEADER--Sort column"_ I'm confused. Are you talking about the row header or the column header?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by… _”stealing the "thunder" from the RowHeaderMouseClick event?”_ … ? …

Comment: Please provide the code that causes this _”thunder stealing”_ aspect. It is unknown “what” the problem is and it would be pure speculation to “guess.” Please clarify what you want/expect to happen. In addition to what is not working as you want/expect. I am just saying that your question… _” how do you stop the DataGridView.Click event from stealing the "thunder" from the RowHeaderMouseClick event?”_ … needs clarification. Stealing the thunder form what? What does stealing the thunder mean in this context? Please help us so we can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I misspoke.  I meant, COLUMN HEADER!  Now that I'm using the correct property--all's good in the hood!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `Click` event, you may use the `MouseClick` event, which will allow you to easily perform a [`HitTest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest) to get information about *where* the click has occurred.

Here's an example:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("RowHeaderMouseClick");
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader) return;

    // Row header clicks won't trigger the following line.
    Console.WriteLine("MouseClick");
}
```

Technically, you could do the same thing with the `Click` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cursorPos = dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    var hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(cursorPos.X, cursorPos.Y);
    if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader) return;

    Console.WriteLine("Click");
}
```

But there's really no reason to since `MouseClick` already gives you the location of the cursor out of the box.

Comment: The hitTestInfo.Type always comes up with NONE--so this won't help.  Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @user1845588 `hitTestInfo.Type` should _not_ be `None` if you click the row header and provide the correct coordinates. Did you try with `Click` or `MouseClick`?